# Processing: Creating Buttons

Tags: processing

I'm trying to create a program that creates three buttons on the right side of the screen.

When I press a button, the entire background will change color (each button will make the background a different color). Whenever the mouse is not pressed, the background will return to white. I'm having trouble understanding how to make the three rectangles into buttons.

**THIS MUST BE DONE WITHOUT A SPECIAL BUTTON METHOD/LIBRARY**

Comment: What is the special button method? Is this for homework?

Comment: Show what you have done so far

Answer (score 2):

[You need to break your problem down into smaller pieces.](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program)

Can you create a program that just shows a single button? Don't even worry about making it interactive yet. Just show a single button at hard-coded coordinates.

Now can you detect when the user clicks in that button? Just print something to the console. Get that working perfectly before moving on.

Now can you get multiple buttons working together? Again, just print somethign to the console, and make sure it works perfectly before moving on.

Finally, can you make it so pressing each button changes the background instead of printing something to the console?

If you get stuck on a specific step, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific technical question. Stack Overflow really isn't designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. So please try something and post an MCVE of a specific step you're stuck on. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check processing's documentation for [`mouseClicked()`](https://processing.org/reference/mouseClicked_.html) and [`mousePressed`](https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed.html).

The former being a method called upon a click, and the later is a boolean that is constantly updated. (So you'd check for it in your `draw()`)

You'd then want to check the `mouseX` and `mouseY` values to see if they are in your desired button's area. (Which would be displayed on screen using `rect()`)